# Deploying multiple Java web apps to Glassfish in one go

Tags: java, web-applications, glassfish

I have multiple (8) WAR files and 1 EAR file that I want to deploy to Glassfish without having to redeploy each application through the Admin Console.

Previously in Tomcat the WAR files could just be dropped into the webapps directory, is there something similar for Glassfish? Using the `asadmin` command to grab a bunch of apps to dpeloy? Preferably for WAR *and* EAR files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep - take a look at /domains/domain1/autodeply - you can drop things straight in there.

(substitute domain1 with your domain if you're working in a custom environment)

(sorry if the folder is off - it's coming from memory at this point)